# How do we set priority with [[NSOperationQueue new]addOperationWithBlock:?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
NSDate *dateStartAutoComplete = [NSDate date];

[[NSOperationQueue new]addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSTimeInterval startFetching = [NSDate.date timeIntervalSinceDate:dateStartAutoComplete];
    PO(@(startFetching));
```

...

Result:

```
2013-03-15 06:00:12.413 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 0.353954017162323
2013-03-15 06:00:13.476 BadgerNew[4120:8d23] @(startFetching): 0.106734037399292
2013-03-15 06:00:13.502 BadgerNew[4120:8d23] @(finishFetching): 0.1373000144958496
2013-03-15 06:00:13.717 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 0.3521299958229065
2013-03-15 06:00:13.869 BadgerNew[4120:675b] @(startFetching): 0.3048880100250244
2013-03-15 06:00:13.918 BadgerNew[4120:675b] @(finishFetching): 0.3537369966506958
2013-03-15 06:00:14.018 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 0.454010009765625
2013-03-15 06:00:16.317 BadgerNew[4120:8847] @(startFetching): 1.014970004558563
2013-03-15 06:00:16.375 BadgerNew[4120:8847] @(finishFetching): 1.072436988353729
2013-03-15 06:00:16.661 BadgerNew[4120:8d23] @(startFetching): 1.045746028423309
2013-03-15 06:00:16.691 BadgerNew[4120:8d23] @(finishFetching): 1.07514101266861
2013-03-15 06:00:16.721 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 1.419299006462097
2013-03-15 06:00:16.759 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 1.142507016658783
2013-03-15 06:00:19.709 BadgerNew[4120:8847] @(startFetching): 1.773845970630646
2013-03-15 06:00:19.795 BadgerNew[4120:8847] @(finishFetching): 1.860616981983185
2013-03-15 06:00:19.900 BadgerNew[4120:907] @(tiTotalTime): 1.965098977088928
```

It took 1.4 seconds between we start the counter and the operation in the NSOperationQueue is executed.

It's not even a single threaded queue.

Answer (score 6):

The NSOperation class contains the methods to set the priority of an operation. You should be able to set the operations priority using the `setQueuePriority:(NSOperationQueuePriority)priority` method on the operation. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591) can give you more details on the constants the method takes.

Since you're adding an operation to the queue you really can't set the priority, and you can't get a reference to the object created for the queue anyway. Instead you should create an [NSBlockOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBlockOperation) in advance and add that to the queue.

Comment: The thing is I am using NSOperationQueue, not NSOperation. So how exactly I will do that?

Comment: @Jim The `addOperationWithBlock` method wraps the block in an operation object. However, you can't get a reference to this object and you really couldn't do anything with it anyway. [Once an operation is the queue it shouldn't be modified.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1)

Comment: NSBlockOperation is a brilliant idea. Thanks Blake!